# Change properties of components

Tags: java, android

I want to change some propertys of a component, like the rotation.

I try it like this:

```
package com.dev.moritz.colora;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class gameActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public ImageView square;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        square = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.game_square);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        square.setRotation(square.getRotation() + 90);
    }

    public void layout_click(View v) {

    }

}
```

But when I start this the app crashs. Without the rotation everything work so there is the problem.
What can I do?

Moritz

Comment: @Moriz try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**   Bind `setContentView()` before the view

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    square = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.game_square);
    square.setRotation(square.getRotation() + 90);
```

**Instead**

```
    square = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.game_square);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    square.setRotation(square.getRotation() + 90);
```